# angular.json assets property changed not working

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-directives

[!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpewr.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpewr.png)

> Blockquote I add the src/data folder path then its not working but when i restart the visual studio then it's working fine. so I have a question how can I refresh the angular.json file. i think this file is not refreshing. any way to refresh angular json file.

```
"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/data"
            ],
```

Comment: In your snapshot, the file angular.json is not saved. Could it be the problem?

Comment: sorry, but I save the file and checked. this is not working at all.

Comment: but when I place any change in angular.json file and close the visual studio code and then again run ng serve cammand. then changes apply.

Comment: why i need to close my visual studio code to apply changes in angular.json . is there any way to apply to angular.json change without closing visual studio code.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about why you had to close vs code, but to apply the changes done in angular.json you must recompile/rebuild your code.So after making changes you have to stop the local host server and then start it again using ng serve.

Comment: that routinely does not work for me either. it seems to be VS Code bug.